# HW: particle subject to central force with exponential logarithmic orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

I've been working on this exercise for some time now and although I've almost got it I can't seem to make it to the end of it. Here is the exercise:

> A particle subject to a central force is orbiting a point in space with a trajectory that is given in plane polar coordinates by a logarithmic spiral: $$r=r_0e^{-\alpha\theta}.$$ How much time will it take the particle to reach the point its orbiting? The particle's initial position is $(r_0, 0)$.

**My reasoning:**

Since the force is central, we know angular momentum will be conserved, and therefore we can write:

$$L = mr^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$

This way, we can perform an intermediate step in which we calculate $\theta(t)$. In doing so, we get:

$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{L}{mr_0^2}e^{2\alpha\theta}$
Since we know the particle will be located at $\theta_0=0$ when $t=0$, we can then integrate like so:

$\int_0^\theta e^{-2\alpha\theta}=\int_0^t \frac{L}{mr_0^2}dt$

Integrating this expression, we get:

$t(\theta) = \frac{mr_0^2}{2\alpha L}(1-e^{-2\alpha\theta})$

At this point, the solution paper states that when $r\longrightarrow 0$ then $\theta \longrightarrow \infty$ which makes no sense whatsoever because you can't know how many revolutions the particle will have completed when it gets to the origin. What I've tried to do instead is to invert the expression so as to find $\theta(t)$ and then plug it into $r$ so I can get $r(t)$ and work with that instead. However, when inverting the function I get:

$$\theta(t) = -\frac{1}{2\alpha}Ln|1-\frac{2\alpha L}{mr_0^2}t|$$

Which, as you can see, has an absolute value, so the function must be expressed in 2 different branches and that makes things much more complicated. Any ideas as to how to approach this exercise in a smarter way are more than welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you know the trajectory to be a logarithmic spiral, and you have figured out the relation between the time $t$ and angle $\theta$. At the starting position, $t=0$ and $\theta=0$. If you look closely at your equation for $t(\theta)$, you may realize that as $\theta$ becomes larger and larger, $t$ approaches a horizontal asymptote. That is to say, $t$ is bounded from above! The argument is then precisely what you discarded from the solution paper. Concretely, you know that as $\theta \rightarrow \infty$, $r \rightarrow 0$, and $t \rightarrow \frac{mr_0^2}{2\alpha L}$.

More physically, the form of the trajectory tells you that it will take an infinite amount of revolutions to reach the origin. Nevertheless, due to angular momentum conservation, each revolution is faster than the previous because the radius becomes smaller. The infinity in the amount of revolutions is compensated by the unlimited increase in angular velocity, so that the particle reaches the origin in a finite amount of time.

Comment: Another way of clarifying this answer is to say that the series of times it takes to complete a particular number of revolutions is convergent in the infinite limit! This is the same resolution to “Zeno’s paradox.”